# CSS: translateY white space between

Tags: html, css

I have simple code with **transform: skew** and **transform: translateY**. I have problem with **white space on bottom** when I use this transforms.

I skewed 2 divs and last I moved with translateY and on bottom is white space which I must remove.

When last div is not transformed with translateY white space is between last and penultimate.

This is only exmaple not real website.

```css
.wrapper0 {
  padding: 200px;
  background: pink;
}

.skews {
  transform: translateY(-150px);
}

.wrapper1 {
  background: lightblue;
  transform: skew(0deg, 5deg);
}

.container1 {
  transform: skew(0deg, -5deg);
  padding: 50px;
}

.wrapper2 {
  background: red;
  transform: skew(0deg, 5deg);
}

.container2 {
  transform: skew(0deg, -5deg);
  padding: 50px;
}

.wrapper1, .wrapper2 {
  padding: 20px;
}

footer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translateY(-300px);
  background: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper0">
            <div class="container0">
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo dolorem maxime magnam tempora, maiores totam fugiat quisquam a minus sunt aut voluptatum at veniam deserunt quibusdam mollitia culpa necessitatibus labore.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="skews">
              <div class="wrapper1">
                <div class="container1">
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo dolorem maxime magnam tempora, maiores totam fugiat quisquam a minus sunt aut voluptatum at veniam deserunt quibusdam mollitia culpa necessitatibus labore.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
                            
                  <div class="wrapper2">
                      <div class="container2">
                          <p>
                              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo dolorem maxime magnam tempora, maiores totam fugiat quisquam a minus sunt aut voluptatum at veniam deserunt quibusdam mollitia culpa necessitatibus labore.
                          </p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
          </div>

<footer>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo dolorem maxime magnam tempora, maiores totam fugiat quisquam a minus sunt aut voluptatum at veniam deserunt quibusdam mollitia culpa necessitatibus labore.</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: try negative margin-top instead

Comment: thank you it working im kokot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a little chaotic. Read in your free time about ":after", ":before", it's very useful. I simplified your code as much as possible. In addition, I have increased response.

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.wrapper0, .wrapper1, .wrapper2, footer {
 height: 200px;
    padding: 100px;
 position: relative;
 align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper0 {
    z-index: 1;
}
.wrapper1 {
    z-index: 2;
}
.wrapper2 {
    z-index: 3;
}
footer {
    z-index: 1;
}
.wrapper0:before, .wrapper1:before, .wrapper2:before {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;

}
.wrapper0:before, .wrapper1:before, .wrapper2:before, footer:before {
 content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.wrapper0:before{
 background: pink;
 height: 500px;
}
.wrapper1:before, .wrapper2:before {
    transform: skew(0deg, 5deg);
 height: 430px;
}
.wrapper1:before{
    background: lightblue;
 
}
.wrapper2:before {
    background: red;
}
footer:before {
    height: 450px;
    top: -50px;
    left: 0;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper0">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo dolorem maxime magnam tempora, maiores totam fugiat quisquam a minus sunt aut voluptatum at veniam deserunt quibusdam mollitia culpa necessitatibus labore.
</div>
<div class="wrapper1">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo dolorem maxime magnam tempora, maiores totam fugiat quisquam a minus sunt aut voluptatum at veniam deserunt quibusdam mollitia culpa necessitatibus labore.
</div>
  
<div class="wrapper2">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo dolorem maxime magnam tempora, maiores totam fugiat quisquam a minus sunt aut voluptatum at veniam deserunt quibusdam mollitia culpa necessitatibus labore.
</div>

<footer>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo dolorem maxime magnam tempora, maiores totam fugiat quisquam a minus sunt aut voluptatum at veniam deserunt quibusdam mollitia culpa necessitatibus labore.
</footer>
```